# How can I change all files as public in folder of gcloud bucket?

Tags: permissions, gcloud, public, bucket

I am currently looking for a way to set permission as public for all files in folder of gcloud bucket.

I need to set the permission individually.

Already refer google document(https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/making-data-public) but only find one by one changes.
(I cannot use object apply way)

Is there any way to change permission as public for all files in files of gcloud bucket?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to change all files from a bucket folder to public you can run:

```
gsutil acl -r ch -u AllUsers:R gs://[BUCKET_NAME]/[FOLDER_NAME]/*
```

Note that the `-r` flag would also make public all files inside subfolders in the original folders (i.e, *gs://[BUCKET_NAME]/[FOLDER_NAME]/[FOLDER_2]/FILE* would **also** be public). Take it out if you don't want that effect.

You can also use the `-m` [flag](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/TopLevelCommandLineOptions) to run the operation i.n parallel by adding it between `gsutil` and `acl` (i.e,  `gsutil -m acl`)

This method relies on the use of [wildcards](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/WildcardNames) ( * ), you can also use them to "filter" files

- gs://bucket/data/prefix* would do the operation with all files that start with "prefix"
- gs://bucket/data/*suffix would filter by files that end with that suffix
- gs://bucket/data/* would use all files

There are other operations (I just listed the basics) in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/WildcardNames).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I am going to try this way :)

Comment: No problem! If you need more help just ask me ;) If you manage to do it consider [accept/upvote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) the question so people with the same question know this is the answer.